# How to use system tray with X11 forwarding?

Tags: xorg, headless, x11-forwarding

I'm using X11 forwarding to use GUI apps from my headless remote server. Everything was fine until I needed to use a program that needs system tray.

Program needs a system tray to work correctly otherwise GUI doesn't show up.

I'm searching for more than 1 hour but still couldn't find any way to handle this situation.

I'm open to any suggestions and solutions. How can I run a GUI program that needs a system tray through X11 forwarding?

Thanks in advance for any advices.